# Generic script to print files of various types in Windows

Tags: windows, scripting, automation, printing, documents

Is there a command or script in Windows to print a file (various file types such as .doc .xls .txt .pdf) to the default printer?

As far as I know one usually has to execute the relevant application (Word, Excel, Notepad, Acrobat Reader) and ask it to print the file, but I could use a generic way of achieving this right now...

Answer (score 1):

I found this out through [this article](http://gregcaporale.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/powershell-to-print-files-automatically/) after being frustrated by Out-Printer.

The synopsis is that using Start-Process should do what you're looking for, if I understood the question:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\somefile.pdf" -Verb Print
```

That will open the file with whatever the default program is and print to the default printer (note: can also specify a different printer). This leaves the program running, but...

```
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\somefile.pdf" -Verb Print -PassThru | %{sleep 10;$_} | kill
```

...will open, print, sleep for a few moments so the program actually has time to print, then kill it.

Comment: To print to a printer other than the default one, use: `Start-Process -FilePath "c:\somefile.pdf" -Verb PrintTo('PrinterName')`